# why my drop down menu is going behind banner in chrome and mozilla?

Tags: html, css, django

I used `django forms`, I tried Z-index style property, but I couldn't get solution.

This is code:

```
<label class="radio">
<input id="id_myclass_only_1" type="radio" name="myclass_only"
{%if form.myclass_only.value == "1"%} checked {%endif%} value="1" /> Post to batch
{{ form.batch|idattr:id_batch }} only
</label>
```

here `{{ form.batch|idattr:id_batch }}` will give drop down list.

Comment: This is unable to be answered in its present form; we need to have the final CSS and HTML to be able to help reliably.

Comment: Hi, can you saw me your code, because when saw your code then finally suggest to you. I hope you understand.

Comment: Incidentally, know that `z-index` doesn't do anything if `position` is `static` (the default value).

Comment: give me css and html so I can help.

Comment: is it possible to suggest me with new css file

Comment: @ChrisMorgan what do you mean static position ? and  the dropdown coming from django forms

Comment: @Kishore: CSS `position: static`.

Comment: @Kishore: as I said, it is not possible to give a good answer without being able to see the HTML and CSS. *You need to share these*, or the question is likely to be closed with no satisfactory answer.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan html file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/k1r8xp02o29y2fo/form_ask_lc.html

Comment: @ChrisMorgan css file path dropbox : https://www.dropbox.com/s/l8e8zvm9q2d5j3p/myCss.css

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, in your case, if `z-index` is not working, I suggest you to use a `position:relative;` along with `z-index`. This shall resolve your issue.

**For Instance,**

```
.yourClass/ #yourId {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Hope this helps.

*PS: you can increase/decrease the `z-index` value as per your requirement/output.*

Comment: Make a jsFiddle of your code with the issue so that it can be checked.

Answer (score -1):

you can use z-index to resolve this

for example

```
  .class {z-index:999}
```